# Why doesn't the console log [Object] instead of my data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a discord bot and I'd like to do a meme command. I store all the memes at a json file `memes.json` and in my index.js I have a variable for get its data `const meme("./memes.json)"`
and in the embed code I started getting errors, Ill leave my code for you to help me.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const meme = require("./memes.json")

function RandomNumbers(min, max) {
   return Math.round(Math.random() * (max -  min) + min);
}

client.on("message", function(message) {

const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
const args = commandBody.split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

//Other commands
}else if(command === 'meme'){
    const memeNumber = RandomNumbers(1, 6)
    const memeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Meme')
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    console.log(meme+'.'+memeNumber)
    .setImage(meme+'.'+memeNumber)
    message.channel.send(memeEmbed)
}
```

```
//memes.json

{
    "1": "https://images7.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED762/5e2e4a5a1d35b.jpeg",
    "2": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9f/8a/5a/9f8a5afe202b973259d76cbd925660e6.jpg",
    "3": "https://i.redd.it/3bfmb513ihd41.jpg",
    "4": "https://memeplanet.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/kiss-plz.jpg",
    "5": "https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/780/926/b82.jpg",
    "6": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/dd/e2/df/dde2df58419e90f30d3abdcb673717f1.png"
}
```

I put that console log in there for check what will it give to me, it gave me this

> [object Object].2

Comment: Please post the contents of `memes.json`

Comment: This is not a [mcve], please make it one.

Comment: I can highly recommend installing the Prettier extension in your code editor, and running it on your source, so that you can post code that is well formatted and formatted universally enough for anyone working with JS to easily read. The lack of semi-colons really impairs legibility here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your json is an object and you try to log  console.log(meme+'.'+memeNumber) which does this:  console.log(meme.toString()+'.'+memeNumber) which {}.toString is [object Object].

You can use console.log() more efectively if you use colon as a separtor (you would not get into these sort of problems), something like: console.log(meme, memeNumber) would print the object stored in meme and the number stored in memeNumber separately.

You can solve your problem by using

`console.log(meme[memeNumber])`

respectively

`.setImage(meme[memeNumber])`

Answer (score 1):

Combining two strings will not make a functional object property reference. You should be using bracket syntax, as you would for arrays.

```js
console.log(meme[memeNumber])
```

```js
const sampleObj = { property: true }; // sample object
const propName = 'property';
console.log(sampleObj[propName]); // brackets work fine in general, but also with variables
```

---

You should never, *ever*, do this, but for the sake of being thorough, you could also `eval` it.

```js
const sampleObj = { property: true };
const propName = 'property';
eval(`console.log(sampleObj.${propName})`);
```